# Drawing a border around my window with GDI, doesn't work?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, border, gdi

I'm trying to draw a border around my window, but my code doesn't seem to work. It doesn't draw anything. Could anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hDC = 0;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    ZeroMemory(&ps, sizeof(PAINTSTRUCT));
    HPEN hp353535 = 0;
    RECT rWnd;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rWnd);

    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
            // I could/should put GetWindowRect() here..
            hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            hp353535 = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 7, RGB(247, 247, 247));
            SelectObject(hDC, hp353535);
            MoveToEx(hDC, rWnd.left, rWnd.top, 0);
            LineTo(hDC, rWnd.right, rWnd.top);
            LineTo(hDC, rWnd.right, rWnd.bottom);
            LineTo(hDC, rWnd.left, rWnd.bottom);
            LineTo(hDC, rWnd.left, rWnd.top);
            DeleteObject(hp353535);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            break;

        // More cases
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GetWindowRect() returns screen coordinates, while drawing uses client coordinates (i.e. relative to the upper-left corner of your window). I think using GetClientRect() helps.

Comment: Ah dangit, it was so simple! Thank you. It works now. - I'll accept your answer as soon as the timelimit lets me.